# How to add custom 3d packages path to pcbnew

Tags: kicad

I'd like pcbnew to find my custom .wrl files for my custom footprints without having the absolute path hardcoded in the .kicad_mod files. I can manipulate the KISYS3DMOD environment variable but then, or course, the standard 3d models are no longer found.

I've also tried to set the path to the model in the .mod file to ${KIPRJMOD}/../packages3d/MyComponent.wrl but that doesn't seem to work. Also putting multiple paths into KISYS3DMOD separated by a colon has no effect (well, the effect is, that neither path works).
I don't want to put my custom packages on every system to /usr/share/kicad/modules/packages3d/, or course.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own variable in the Preferences->Configure Paths...
You might need to restart KiCad for the variable to be seen by other KiCad editors.

[image]

Then edit your footprint module and in 3D Settings add your custom wrl. Once added the absolute path will be replaced with the above defined path variable.

[image]

I'm running KiCad v5.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

I have used defined paths in *PCBNew/Preferences/Library*.

[image]

When 3D model resides in a directory on leaf of any path then relative path is used.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't even have PCBNew/Tools/Library. I'm currently running rev5528, should I update?

Comment: Same with the nightly build 6151

Comment: Hmm, I'm using old *(2013-jul-07)-testing* on WinXP. It's *Preferences/Library* (I've fixed in original post) in English locale.